# Creating a space in between values in Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are two types of values in cell A of my spreadsheet

**Value type 1:** Have a space in between the postcode district and sub postcode, as the postcode district is less than ten (i.e. MK1-MK9)

```
MK1 1AS
```

**Value type 2:** Have no space in between, as the postcode district is greater than ten (i.e. MK10-MK46)

```
MK170DB
```

What would be the best way of splitting the second group of values into something like this:

```
MK17 0DB
```

I was thinking of some pseudo code in the the vein of:

> if the value at the 4th character (counting from the right) in `MK170DB` is not an empty space
>
> then count 4 spaces and create an empty character, leaving it like this `MK17 0DB`
>
> if not then presume that the 4th character is a empty space (i.e. `MK1 1AS`) and leave it

As I just need to run this operation once to cleanse my data, I was thinking about creating a formula in column B that references column A and does the necessary cleansing. I would then replace the values in col A with what I have in col B.

Can anyone tell me whether the logic I have proposed can be executed in Excel or if there is a better way of doing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data in **A1,** in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",A1)),LEFT(A1,4) & " " & MID(A1,5,999),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I came up with, which appears to work...

```
=IF(MID(A1,4, 1)=" ",A1,REPLACE(A1,5,0," "))
```